# Name Effects On Personality

Tags: hadith-interpretation, islamic-basis, naming

I want to know that is there any effects of name on the personality?

I hear that *always choose a good name (which has positive meaning).*

Answer (score 1):

It is known that the name usually has an effect on the person who carries it.and our beloved Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) changed bad names to good names.As for the importance of names in Islam more generally, I recall a saying of the Prophet (SAW) in which he urged parents to give their children good names. It was also said that when people came to the Prophet (SAW) bearing names that were derogatory, he gave them new and better names.if our prophet change bad names of people into good so its mean that  a name definitely effect on personality of child
Ibn al-Qayyim said:

Because names have meanings, these meanings will inevitably have an effect on the person who carries the name. Names have an effect on the things that are named, and the things that are named have an effect on their names, whether they are beautiful or ugly, light or heavy, subtle or crude.